# Configure distributable JRuby/Rails with Warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

To make a web application as distributable, we can configure this in the standard web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <!-- ... -->

    <distributable/>

  <!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

But I'm using JRuby/Rails and building the WAR file with Warbler. Is there anyway to do this in warble.rb configuration file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. It's also described in Warbler [README](https://github.com/jruby/warbler#webxml)

1) Copy the [web.xml.erb](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/web.xml.erb) to your /config/

2) Add the element distributable under the root element web-app:

```
<web-app>
  <!-- ... -->

  <distributable/>

  <!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

That's all!